# HTTPS $.ajax request loading in HTTP

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, https

I have an ajax post request from `https://siteABC.com` for `https://siteABC.com/php/message_sys.php` but the request is being loaded as `http://www.siteABC.com` and due to the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) I am unable to load this request.

CORS is not required since I am not leaving the domain and I have other requests that work just fine as well.

Here's my ajax:

```
$("input.send").click(function(){
    var to = $(this).prev().attr('id');
    var input = $(this).prev().val();
  $.post('https://siteABC.com/php/message_sys.php',{
        account_name: to,
        author: "<?php echo $user_name?>",
        text: input
    },
    //response
    function(data,status){
    if(status == "Sent"){
            $(this).prev().prev().html('Sent');
        }
  });
});
```

I should also note that I've added some code to remove any www. and change http protocols into https on the .htaccess file, pardon my coding:

```
AddType text/html .html
AddHandler default-handler .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^siteABC\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://siteABC.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I guess I could use 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the header but for some reason every other request works just fine.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, solved:

I forgot to put the onSubmit="return false;" value on the form tag! :D Works great now.

Thanks anyways!